# Is my carbon frame done?

Tags: frames, safety, carbon

I have a carbon trek Emonda bicycle. Today, my rear derailleur got caught in my wheel. As a result, the rear derailleur is bent, the rear derailleur hanger snapped off, the chain got twisted and the right seat stay got scratched.

Is the scratch on my right seat stay too dangerous to ride again? It goes about 1-2 mm at the deepest part of the scratch.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I do when I am unsure if a carbon fiber component is safe to use or needs replacing or repairing?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/76022/what-do-i-do-when-i-am-unsure-if-a-carbon-fiber-component-is-safe-to-use-or-need)

Comment: My uneducated opinion is that it looks okay. There appears to be a metric f*ck ton of paint and primer on that frame. I’d carefully chip off all the paint in that area to assess purely the carbon damage.

Comment: @MaplePanda: In the second photo it does look quite deep and looks like it could have actually cut some carbon fibers or glass fiber.

Comment: It looks to me like delamination has occurred.  I wouldn't ride it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not ride that frame as-is.

Whether it is repairable or not needs a hands-on inspection by a competent carbon fibre frame repairer in person.  So you need to strip everything else off the bike and send/take the bare frame to someone who can advise professionally.

Comment: Thanks, I will repair it just in case

Comment: @Bubblesphere be prepared for the fact that repair may not be (economically) feasible, then be happy if it turns out to be so!

Answer (score 8):

The seat stays are always in compression, take very little load and have no side loading. If you ride the bike on smooth roads you might not experience any further failure, but this is not ''sensible.''

The damage is absolutely repairable and may actually not cost very much. Certainly worth doing.

However, your lifetime warranty is no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks, I got a quote of 350$ for the repairs