# Is it safe to ride the carbon bike with a small crack on the bottom of the chain stay? Looks cosmetic but fails the tap test

Tags: repair, carbon

The chainstay cracked after air travel.[image]
**Update:**
I have brought the frame to a carbon repair shop for repair. The cost would be 500ish, including the touch-up paint.

**Tips for future flight travelers**:
Either use Bikeflights.com (which provides insurance) or avoid put hard items (e.g. bike tools) in the bike travel bag.

Comment: The chainstays are very high stress areas. Have it repaired.

Comment: Related. https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/76022/what-do-i-do-when-i-am-unsure-if-a-carbon-fiber-component-is-safe-to-use-or-need

Comment: Chainstays near the dropouts should be loaded in pretty much pure tension. Repair should be simple.

Comment: Thanks for the update and go ahead and select a "correct" answer to give the author bonus points.

Comment: Compare the cost of repair against the cost of an equivalent replacement frame that will take all the existing components.  That said, supply issues in these C19 days make it hard to find the right items.

Comment: @maplepanda and torsion

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Only the manufacturer or a competent frame repair person can tell you of it is safe. It does not look just cosmetic to me, but I have no qualification whatsoever.

However, this small damage is very likely to be well repairable. Just ask a competent bikeshop or a dedicated carbon frame repair workshop.

Comment: With carbon treat anything suspicious as not safe. It will fail without warning!

Comment: Absolutely, once it is more than a paint chip, be vigilant and exercise caution.

Comment: The repair will be easier and less costly if it is done before it becomes catastrophic.

Comment: A severe dent or scratch in an aluminium or steel or titanium frame in that location can be just as dangerous. It’s not really carbon specific.