# carbon frame bike ktm revelator 4000 2017 damaged

Tags: frames, carbon

KTM 2017 revelator 4000 in the bottom of the frame I have noticed this failure/puncture. Would you trust the damage here in the picture?[image]

Comment: I'd be more worried about the state of your tyres. A little black touch up paint will fix the frame

Comment: Thanks, yes the tyres were planned to be changed. It is my first time buying a nice street bike so I was worried about this puncture on the frame that might get bigger.

Comment: It’s just a paint chip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I do when I am unsure if a carbon fiber component is safe to use or needs replacing or repairing?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/76022/what-do-i-do-when-i-am-unsure-if-a-carbon-fiber-component-is-safe-to-use-or-need)

Comment: Regarding the tyres: They look like Conti GP4000s. They crack relatively easily, but maybe OP has ridden them at too low pressure.