# How bad/deep is this chip on a carbon fiber bike frame?

Tags: frames, carbon, damage, paint

Does it cut into the fiber or just some paint chip?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I do when I am unsure if a carbon fiber component is safe to use or needs replacing or repairing?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/76022/what-do-i-do-when-i-am-unsure-if-a-carbon-fiber-component-is-safe-to-use-or-need)

Comment: Are you by any chance being tempted to buy a fancy frame at a great price online because it is 'slightly' damaged? If so, my recommendation would be not to...

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it’s through the paint and into the first carbon layer (but not through it).

I’m no expert, but I don’t think it’s too bad, especially in this location. Make sure it doesn’t get any more damaged (looks like the chainring or chain repeatedly made contact?) and I think it’s still safe to ride.

Comment: I think I agree, although I'm also not an expert. The grey layer should be the primer for the paint.