# Chip in carbon seat tube?

Tags: frames, carbon, damage, seattube

I pulled out the seatpost on my Giant TCR and notice something like a chip in the seat tube, are defects like this normal?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I do when I am unsure if damaged carbon fiber is safe to use or needs replacing or repairing?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/76022/what-do-i-do-when-i-am-unsure-if-damaged-carbon-fiber-is-safe-to-use-or-needs-re)

Answer (score 3):

Those small paint chips? Look harmless. You can also see a few minor surface voids inside the tube from the manufacturing process which should also be harmless.