# Super-glue for minor scrapes on carbon fiber frame - below the top-coat

Tags: carbon, damage

I scraped my frame on a curb about 1 mm deep in a couple places near the rear axle.  (it's a 2021 TREK Domane SL-7).  Another post stated that chopper pilots routinely use super glue and baking soda to seal small nicks on carbon fiber rotor blades.  Is this okay for skin-deep blemishes below the top coat (not major holes) on a bike?  Has anything changed in epoxy-like technology for coating a minor scrape on a frame?

From a materials science perspective, my gut feeling is to apply something to the scrapes to permanently lock up any fiber threads that potentially could begin to move under stress/shear.  I wouldn't want anything small to snowball into something larger(?)

Comment: Possibly related -> [link](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/76022/what-do-i-do-when-i-am-unsure-if-damaged-carbon-fiber-is-safe-to-use-or-needs-re). A clear-coat chip is just a chip, everything beyond (fibers torn or worse) needs professional repair, but that is hard to judge from your description. Can you add some detail shots of the scrape?

Comment: Thanks @DoNut - very good reading: comprehensive and professional.

Comment: That's a heavily cited question here. I'd say, if you have the feeling that you scratched more than the surface, contacting some nearby repair shop for a quick assessment would be a good idea. A single fix on one chainstay shouldn't cost the world and is probably worth doing on a decent bike like a Domane.

Comment: It looks like there are merely just scratches in the paint or topcoat, but I know my chain has been caught between the seat post and the smaller sprocket a couple time - thus I need to ask the mechanic at TREK to inspect for any damage which needs professional care.  I am sure the TREK dealer knows about how to approach this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fibers won't move as they are a laminate with epoxy resin. They float in glue, even if there is very little glue. U could use superglue to cosmeticaly close the hole. Keep an eye on it periodicaly as superglue is not made for oustide use, water, sweat and UV rays will eventualy damage it.