# Specialized Sirrus bicycle, fork cracked

Tags: fork, damage, carbon-fork

I have a Specialized that was a gift, but have some problems at the front fork.

The fork is cracked, as per Photo:

Can someone help me to discover how to repair?

[image]

---

Other photos of the bike:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! I think you'll have to give a lot more information to make this answerable.

Comment: Valuations are off-topic here, but for the estimation of the repair, you need to go to a specialized dealer. The bike has a FutureShock suspension, which means that forks are non standard.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the lack of irformation.

The fork its cracked. I uploaded one more photo with the issue

Comment: If the fork is cracked, you need to show it to a carbon fiber repair specialist. It is likely repairable, but not really DIY. They may also say that it is not repairable or not worth repairing. You should be able to get a quote before the repair.

Comment: OK, you've added in a picture of the damaged fork - looks like a crack in the carbon due to impact or squeezing the fork arm - you won't get a number here but maybe [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/76022/what-do-i-do-when-i-am-unsure-if-damaged-carbon-fiber-is-safe-to-use-or-needs-re) is worth a read.  Assuming that carbon Cirrus is no cheap bike (prices from 2000€), a fork repair by a carbon expert is feasible, I'd say.

Comment: Is the purple colour a sticker that has torn or does the damage go deeper into the black carbon ?

Comment: The purple colour is not a sticker and the damage goes deeper.

Comment: My doubt is... It's better if I put a new fork (not necessarily in carbon) or if with crack prepared is totally safe to ride the bike again?

Comment: I'm also having difficults to discover where I can get more information about the bike. I'm not sure about the exact model of the bike, so I don't know where I should start to look in case I opted for changing the fork.